# Android: Installed application hasn't icon on the main screen

Tags: android, icons

I  have a simple Android app (Android Studio wizard - Basic Activity). After compilation and installation it successfully runs on my device. But it doesn't have an icon on the **main screen** (even like as Android default icon)! And as result **I can't relaunch application**.

How to resolve this problem?

Apps installed from the Google Play has an icons - it's OK.

I tested several devices, and the problem occurs only on one device - **Hisense A6** (with dual screens - AMOLED and e-ink on back side).

**UPD** (07.02.2020): After my investigation I figured out that signed applications installed successfully with icons on main screen!
Android settings: Developer mode, Verify apps over USB (Check apps installed via ADB/ADT) - is **OFF**

Android 9.0

Phone model: Hisense A6 (HLTE700E)

Build version: PKQ1.181105.001

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.apps.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apps.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apps.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please update the code for "MainActivity" .So that it is reduce the complexity of getting solutions

Comment: you'll find it as Android logo icon

Comment: Actually in your screenshots there's an icon: you can customize it with `icon` and `roundIcon` in your manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my investigations I figured out that signed applications installed successfully with icons on main screen.
I think it is a feature of this one phone.